# Guitar intonations sounds a bit off?

Tags: guitar, intonation

So I've got this Les Paul Custom a couple of weeks ago and it feels and plays great. I intonated it perfectly when I first got it too. So today I wanted to test how is intonation holding up and did some tests with perfect 5th. I played 6th fret on low E and compared it to 11th on B. I then played 6th on B and compared it to 11th on G but it sounded sharp in comparison. Basically 6th on B sounds the same as 10th on G whereas it should be sounding the same on 11th.I tried to move a screw a bit on my tune o matic but it just doesn't bulge anymore due to lack of space. What should I do?

Comment: I think you may be confused, or have mistyped your question.  In standard tuning,  the 6th fret of the B string is F and the 10th fret of the G string is F.  The 11th fret of the G string would be F#.

Comment: A simple way to test intonation is to compare the fretted note and harmonic at the 12th fret; they should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on jonrsharpe's comment a little, you need to tune your guitar up and fret the note at the 12th fret so it's perfectly in tune. Then play the harmonic at the 12th fret and whether it's sharp or flat will tell you if you need to change the intonation.

However, since you've probably adjusted the intonation already, what you should do is;

- loosen the strings
- make sure the intonation screws are centered, so you have the maximum possible range of making it sharp or flat
- tune your guitar like normal
- check the intonation and adjust, as mentioned earlier.

EDIT;

Just to mention as well, remember the intonation will change as the neck moves and also if you change string gauges or tuning. It doesn't take a lot to mess the intonation around, but it all depends on the guitar and how well it's built as well!